Supposed to be a simple question about entropy
Let say there is an urn which contains balls of different color. It is a well known formula to calculate entropy of balls in the urn:
H = - sum Pi*log(Pi)
where Pi = Mi/N, where Mi - number of balls of i-th color and N is total number of balls in the urn.
Value of entropy is at maximum when there are same number of balls of each color and 0 if all balls are same color.
That's basic.
Now let say we add a few more urns. How to calculate entropy now?
Intuitively, entropy should be maximal if there are same number of balls of each color in each urn.
Entropy should be 0 if all urns have same number of balls of same color (and no other balls).
In between, there is some entropy if all urns have same number of balls but each urn has balls of its own color; or if urns have not even number of balls or if some urns are empty etc.
We can calculate entropy separately for each urn using the formula above; we can calculate entropy between urns using similar formula; we can try to combine these entropies using arithmetic, but I feel there must be an elegant clean formula which I struggle to figure out.
Update
Got an answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/644241/36126


we can try to combine these entropies using arithmetic, but I feel there must be an elegant clean formula which I struggle to figure out.

But it turns out, the elegant clean formula is just adding them up. Assuming the urn contents are independent, their entropy is additive $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y)$ and you can thus just sum up their individual entropies.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Alternative_characterization_via_additivity_and_subadditivity

yes but what if urns are filled with balls of its own colors? entropy of each urn will be 0; sum of entropies will be 0; but there is some information that 1st urn contains red balls, 2nd blue balls, etc. therefore entire entropy should not be zero

Shannon entropy is not information, instead it is how much additional information you would need to fully resolve the internal state of the system. If each urn has the color of all its balls pre-assigned then it can exist only in one state and its entropy is 0 ... and so is the global entropy because then there is also globally only one possible state in which the urns can be in.

All urns with ball of its own color and All urns with balls of mixed colors is not the same state. Entropy values should be different. Your formula doesnt take into account.
It could be address just adding to the sum another entropy of balls between urns but I am not sure if it is the best approach. Seems there must be another more elegant way.

sorry I mean all balls in all urns are same color is not the same state as all balls in same urn have same color but each urn has its own unique color of balls.

If the system can be in only one state, no matter if it is "all balls in all urns are green" or "all balls in urn 1 are blue and all balls in urn 2 are red", then its entropy is by definition 0.

If the system can be in multiple states then it will have non-zero entropy. And in this case if states of its subsystems are independent of each other, the total entropy is just sum of the entropies of its parts. For example, "each of the urns can be either all balls green or all balls yellow with the same probability, independent of each other", then there can be 4 states: both green, both yellow, 1 green 2 yellow, 1 yellow 2 green -> it has 2 bits of entropy, while each urn can be in 2 states, giving it 1 bit of entropy, and thus 2 =1 + 1.
